# Teradata date time subtraction and conversion

Tags: date, datetime, teradata

How can I convert the following Oracle conversion to Teradata:

```
select
round((current_timestamp - ah.adate) - (ah.ahdate-ah.adate),1) 
,round(ah.ahdate-ah.addate,1) 
from actions ah
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL. What data types are these? Dates? Timestamps? What is the `ROUND` function doing here?

Comment: @Jnevill These are timestamps: ahdate:2015-04-10 07:08:34.000 adate:2015-04-09 16:30:14.000 I have no idea about round function. Its an oracle query

Answer (score 0):

I believe one of the follow comparisons should work in Teradata:

```
SELECT Current_Timestamp - CAST(ah.addate AS TimeStamp(6)) DAY (4) TO SECOND(4) AS TimeInterval
     , Current_Date - CAST(ah.addate AS DATE) DAY(4) AS DayInterval /* May Not be necessary as two dates can be subtracted/added without INTERVAL */
     , Current_Date - ah.addate AS DayDifference /* If AdDate is a DATE in Teradata */
FROM actions ah
```

**EDIT**: Break down difference to seconds between timestamps and then use math to calculate days between two timestamps as FLOAT.

```
SELECT (((EXTRACT (DAY FROM (Current_Timestamp - Timestamp '2015-04-01 21:13:40' DAY TO SECOND)) * 86400)
    + (EXTRACT (HOUR FROM (Current_Timestamp - Timestamp '2015-04-01 21:13:40' DAY TO SECOND)) * 3600)
    + (EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM (Current_Timestamp - Timestamp '2015-04-01 21:13:40' DAY TO SECOND)) * 60)
    + (EXTRACT (SECOND FROM (Current_Timestamp - Timestamp '2015-04-01 21:13:40' DAY TO SECOND))) AS FLOAT)) / 86400.00
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly as sin, but it will get you number of days to a single decimal place from the subtraction of two intervals.

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(
        STRTOK(CAST((TIMESTAMP '2017-04-17 07:08:34.000'  - TIMESTAMP '2015-04-09 16:30:14.000' DAY(4) TO HOUR) AS VARCHAR(10)),' ',1) + 
        (STRTOK(CAST((TIMESTAMP '2017-04-17 07:08:34.000'  - TIMESTAMP '2015-04-09 16:30:14.000' DAY(4) TO HOUR) AS VARCHAR(10)),' ',2)/24)
        ,1)
```

The tricky part here is that when you subtract two `TIMESTAMPs`, what you end up with is an `INTERVAL` data type. We convert that interval data type to `HOUR`, then cast the results as a `VARCHAR`, which in this example looks like `738 15`. That's 738 days and 15 hours.

Using `STRTOK()`, we can pick out the days (the first token) and then add in the number of hours (second token) divided by 24.

The result is then rounded.

Perhaps there is a less involved way, but I haven't discovered it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Used this solution:
, trim(abs((CAST(ah.ahdate  AS DATE) - CAST(ah.adate AS DATE)))) 
,(cast (trim(abs((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ah.ahdate)) - abs(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ah.adate )))) as varchar(10)))/24